# Calculating the residue of $f(z) = \frac{z(z-1)^{\frac{1}{3}}\sin(\frac{1}{z})}{(z^2+1)^3\sin(z)}$ at $z=0$.

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I am stuck on how to classify the singular points of $ f(z) = \frac{z(z-1)^{\frac{1}{3}}\sin(\frac{1}{z})}{(z^2+1)^3\sin(z)}$ at $z=0$.

I know that the singularities are $z=n\pi$, $\frac{+}{-}i$ where $n$ is any integer.

I am also sure that z = $\frac{+}{-}i$ correspond to third order poles and that $z=n\pi$ correspond to simple poles when $n$ is not equal to $0$. I think this because the numerator is not $0$ for these singularities, so I can just find the order of the zero for the denominator to determine the pole of $f(z)$.

So all that leaves is $z=0$, and I am very unsure of where to start. I have messed around with the Taylor Series but nothing seems to work?

Comment: I have found something, by manipulating the taylor series zsin(1/z)/sinz that gives infinity at z = 0, so maybe at z = 0 we have a 0th order pole? If thats even a thing...

Comment: Wait, so the answer could be that 0 is an essential singularity?!?!?!?!??!